# Disclosing current workplace name

Tags: resume

Is it right to disclose current workplace name (of which I am presently still under bond period) to my potential employer. If not then is specifying "ABC", a dummy name to the present organization correct way of representing information on the resume.

I intend to leave my present organization in order to pursue more lucrative opportunities being offered outside.

<sub>"Bond period" rules are, it's a fresher position hence the slated bond, failure to abide with may lead to a penalty amount being deposited by the employee.</sub>

Comment: What are the rules governing this "bond period"?

Comment: Its a fresher position hence the slated bond, failure to abide with may lead to a penalty amount being deposited by the employee.

Comment: Are you planning on paying the penalty and switching before the bond period ends, or are you near the end of the period and will switch the week after the period ends? Location?

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly normal to do so, and failing to will raise some eyebrows, possibly cost you an opportunity. There certainly isn't currently a standard way to mark this on your CV/resume.

Personally, I've had one decent resume that said "Disclosure on interview" in place of the company name. It was pretty obvious to me that they didn't want to risk an agent accidentally spreading the word to his boss that he was leaving, so I interviewed him and asked him then.

But, I later found out, someone else in a different department had rejected his resume on that detail alone. So, I guess it depends a lot on who is reading your resume.

Sad thing is that I also can't advise you not to worry about it. I've seen cases where agents have sent a resume to the boss of the candidate. And there's very little recourse (in any country I'm aware of) if they should do so.

But I will say that putting a dummy (real or otherwise) company name in there, is going to increase your chance of interview, but also increase the chances of such an accident happening. Plus, you're likely to get rejected for lying, once the truth comes out, anyway.

Comment: Appreciate the help. But this sure continues to make me indecisive.

Comment: @learning_fly: Note my last edit. I think hiding it is a bad idea, but an understandable one. If you're going to do it then make it very obvious: "Disclosure on interview" was good, in my opinion, but apparently not good enough for my colleague.

Comment: "I've seen cases where agents have sent a resume to the boss of the candidate." Of course, this risk might even be higher if you don't disclose your employer.  Your resume just happens to match very well with the job you just left, so there's a good chance a recruiter will send it by accident.  I've had that happen to me before.